# Настройка nginx как прокси apache2

Tags: nginx

Никогда еще не настраивал `nginx`, вот решил исправить ситуацию. Хочу настроить его как прокси для `apache2`. Вот конфиги:

/apache2/ports.conf

```
Listen 8080

<IfModule ssl_module>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_gnutls.c>
    Listen 443
</IfModule>
```

/nginx/sites-avaliable/sd.ru:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name www.sd.ru sd.ru;
location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|tar|wav|bmp|rtf|swf|ico|flv|txt|docx|xlsx)$ {
root /home/a1essandro/PHP/symfony/web/;
index index.html app.php;
access_log off;
expires 30d;
}
location / {
proxy_pass http://sd.ru:8080/;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-for $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_connect_timeout 60;
proxy_send_timeout 90;
proxy_read_timeout 90;
proxy_redirect off;
proxy_set_header Connection close;
proxy_pass_header Content-Type;
proxy_pass_header Content-Disposition;
proxy_pass_header Content-Length;
}
}
```

apache2/sites-avaliable/symfony.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerName sd.ru

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /home/a1essandro/PHP/symfony/web/

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

`nginx` [пере]запускается (методом `sudo service nginx reload`), ошибки в путях были, но я их решил. Сейчас при открытии sd.ru:8080 - открывает сайт, но sd.ru - мозила пишет, что `Попытка соединения не удалась`, не возвращая никаких данных в ответе.

Как исправить? Заранее благодарю.

**UPDATE**

логи nginx:

```
2015/12/22 08:19:57 [emerg] 30325#0: invalid URL prefix in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/sd.ru:7
2015/12/22 08:36:28 [emerg] 31545#0: host not found in upstream "sd" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/sd.ru:15
```

Это я исправил, ошибки записывались при попытке старта сервиса.

Логи апача:

```
[Tue Dec 22 10:49:15.341722 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 31975] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Tue Dec 22 10:49:15.655073 2015] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 31975] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.14 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Dec 22 10:49:15.655169 2015] [core:notice] [pid 31975] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Comment: Это конечно вопрос, а не комментарий... Автор, а в чем плюс такой схемы работы???

Comment: http://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/57521/ и http://habrahabr.ru/post/120814/

Comment: В первую очередь надо б соответствующие логи обоих серверов почитать

Comment: В том то и дело, что логи молчат. Обновляю страницу множество раз, в логах старые записи.

Comment: а *http://sd.ru:8080/* с сервера доступен? И зачем так? Почему не *http://localhost:8080/*?

Comment: А логи указано куда писать? Может в другое место пишет? Или настройку убрали, вот и не пишутся. Логи апача тоже пустые? А что `netstat -anp | grep ':80.*LISTEN'` говорит? nginx нормально работает? Может он не запустился, а вместо него апач висит? У nginx'а обе ошибки исправили?

Comment: tcp6  0  0 :::8080  :::* LISTEN 3397/apache2 - примерно такое. По поводу логов, я так понимаю, что если для конкретного хоста не указывать - они будут писаться в файл по умолчанию (прописан в nginx.conf). Не localhost:8080 - потому что несколько виртуальных хостов

Comment: ну т.е. nginx не запущен, либо слушает другие порты, иначе выдал бы и его тоже. Этот сайт добавлен в sites-available? error.log nginx'а смотрели? `ps ax | grep nginx` что-нибудь показывает? Сделайте `netstat -anp | grep 'LISTEN.*nginx'` - увидите на чем nginx висит

Comment: Первая команда выдает 4319 pts/0 S+ 0:00 grep --color=auto nginx. Вторая - ничего не выдает

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33308/discussion-between-bopoh-and-a1essandro).

Answer (score 1):

Для простого проксирования этого запроса будет достаточно, статику в данном случае будет отдавать апач.

```
    server {
     listen 80;
     server_name www.sd.ru sd.ru;

     location / {
         location / {
         proxy_pass http://sd.ru:8080/;
         proxy_set_header  Host       $host;
         proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
     }
   }
```